# Como pegar dados de um Select MySQLi e fazer envio de newsletter

Tags: php

Estou tentando enviar uma newsletter depois de uma busca no meu banco de dados, é a primeira vez que estou usando a extensão MySQLi e estou tento alguma dificuldade ao percorrer o segundo WHILE e creio que não está da forma correta, fiz assim:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT id, email FROM newsletter WHERE status = 1 AND enviado = 0";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error." [$sql]"); 
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
     $id = $row['id'];
     $email = $row['email'];     
    }

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $mail->setFrom('emailsdosite@moveissaobento.com.br', 'Newsletter');
    $mail->addAddress($email);
    $mail->Subject = 'Envio Newsletter';
    $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('news.php'), dirname(__FILE__));
    $mail->send();
    $mail->ClearAddresses();

    $sqlEdicao_usuarios = " UPDATE newsletter SET enviado = 1 WHERE id = $id ";
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $sqlEdicao_usuarios;
    $fim = mysql_query( $sqlEdicao_usuarios,$conexao ) or die ( "Erro alterando dados no Banco de Dados" ); 


}
```

Comment: Por que o primeiro while? Acredito que você pode fazer tudo de um único while...

Comment: Pego o Id e e-mail no primeiro WHILE e tento enviar minha newsletter pelo while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())

Comment: ao invez de fazer o segundo while, você pode colocar tudo dentro do primeiro, não faz sentido usar 2 whiles

Comment: Adicione seu código tudo ao primeiro while, e modifique suas variáveis de $id por $row['id'], e $email por $row['email']; Além de que o primeiro while, só manterá no $id e $email, o último id e email encontrados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teste da seguinte forma:

Coloquei o código do segundo while no primeiro assim o eliminando (pois não havia necessidade dele) e simplificando seu código também.

> O que acontecia antes: o primeiro while somente guardava um id e email na variável $id, $email, o que provavelmente causava os problemas (Isso quando retornava algum resultado...).

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT id, email FROM newsletter WHERE status = 1 AND enviado = 0";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error." [$sql]"); 
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $mail->setFrom('emailsdosite@moveissaobento.com.br', 'Newsletter');
    $mail->addAddress($row['email']);
    $mail->Subject = 'Envio Newsletter';
    $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('news.php'), dirname(__FILE__));
    $mail->send();
    $mail->ClearAddresses();

    $sqlEdicao_usuarios = " UPDATE newsletter SET enviado = 1 WHERE id = $row['id']";// ou jogue em uma variável e substitua por ela.... ($id = $row['id'])
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $sqlEdicao_usuarios;
    $fim = mysql_query( $sqlEdicao_usuarios,$conexao ) or die ( "Erro alterando dados no Banco de Dados" ); 
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Rafael Withoeft, foi de grande ajuda.

Comment: @Sergio Pronto... acho que assim está bom, o que acha? adventistapr.. por nada.

Comment: Olá @Rafael Withoeft, como posso pegar o mysql_num_rows?

Comment: $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); ou: $result->num_rows; Caso precise da documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php