# Comando sql não executa via php

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, post, login

Estou tendo um problema com a minha consulta ao bd. Quero fazer uma página de login com o seguinte formulário:

```html
 <form method="post" action="Login.php">
   Email:<br>
   <input class="form-control" placeholder="Seu email" type="text" name="email">
   <br>
   Senha:<br>
   <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Sua senha" name="senha">
   <br>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-embossed btn-info" name="Entrar" value="Entrar">
</form>
```

E utiliza a página Login.php:

```html
<?php
//Conectando ao banco de dados
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "authenticationteste");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
}

//$nomeUser = $_POST["nomeUser"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
//$senha = $_POST["senha"];
//Consultando banco de dados
$res   = $mysqli->query("SELECT senha FROM login WHERE email='".$email."';");

//email não encontrado
if (!$res) {
    echo "Query failed: (".$mysqli->errno.") ".$mysqli->error;
}
```

Porém, quando coloco qualquer informação na label do email, o laço sempre me retorna ENTROU, (mesmo que não esteja cadastrado no banco). Já fiz um teste para exibir a variável vinda pelo método post, e ela recebe exatamente o que eu escrevi no campo, mas na hora da consulta ao banco, esse valor não é utilizado. 
Tentei de muitos jeitos, mas a consulta nunca funciona. Essa é a primeira vez que acontece algo do tipo com o meu código, então se puderem ajudar eu agradeço.

Repito: O método post está funcionando, ele armazena na variável corretamente. o problema está na hora de usa-la na consulta .

Agradeço!

Comment: Aparece alguma mensgem de erro?

Comment: não, nenhuma, aparentemente funciona

Comment: Tem que ser mysqli? mysql não funciona?

Comment: Dê um var_dump() em $mysqli->connect_errno
assim: var_dump($mysqli->connect_errno);  antes do if

Comment: vc quer pegar a senha? precisa de um `fetch_array/fetch()`

Comment: @DiegoMoreira com o var_dump($mysqli->connect_errno); retornou int(0)

Comment: Yeah! Em sintaxe em funções de classe, pode e deve usar aspas simples, crase não funciona, quebra o código quando executa.
O que tem que ser feito é um fetch_array, como o @rray disse. Assim você tem acesso ao retorno do query.

Comment: Recomendo esse link: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: O que você precisa, como melhor exemplo, pode usar isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50919/como-pegar-dados-de-um-select-mysqli-e-fazer-envio-de-newsletter

Espero que consiga, abs

Comment: coloquei $result = mysqli_fetch_array($email);  e ele retornou: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in...

Answer (score 1):

**Edição**

**Exemplo com PDO**

```
<?php
// Primeira coisa: recebe os cabeçalhos e envia
$email = $_POST["email"];

// Tenta trazer os dados do banco de dados
try {
    // Cria objeto PDO
    $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=authenticationteste', 'root', '');

    // Query que será executada. Recebe o parâmetro :email
    $query = "select senha from login where email= :email";

    // Prepara a query para execução
    $consulta = $conexao->prepare($query, array(PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));

    // Atribui o parametro $email a :email na consulta
    $consulta->bindParam(':email', $email);

    // Executa a consulta ao banco de dados
    $consulta->execute();

    // Conta quantaslinhas foam retornadas do banco de dados
    $numero_linhas = $consulta->rowCount();

    // Se tiver pelo menos uma linha, retorna os valores...
    if($numero_linhas !== 0){
        $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Faça o que bem entender com o resultado
        // você pode usar:
        /**
         while($resultado = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
             echo $resultado['coluna_desejada']
         }
         */
    } else {
        echo "Nenhum resultado no banco de dados para o argumento de pesquisa";
    }

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Deu ruim: ".$ex->getMessage();
}
```

Não testei, porque só tenho o SQL Server aqui, mas aqui vai:

```
<?php
// Primeira coisa: recebe os cabeçalhos e envia
$email = $_POST["email"];

// Tenta trazer os dados do banco de dados
try {
    // Conexão com o banco de dados
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "authenticationteste");

    // Consulta o banco de dados
    //TODO: escapar as strings !IMPORTANTE

    $query = 'select senha from login where email="'.$email.'"';

    // Imprime informações sobre a query
    var_dump($query);

    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);

    if ($resultado->num_rows == 1) {
        $linha = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
        // Faça o que quiser com o resultado usando, por exemplo, $linha['senha']
    } else {
        echo "Nenhum resultado no banco de dados para o argumento de pesquisa";
    }

    $mysqli->close();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Deu ruim: ".$ex->getMessage();
}
```

Dependendo da complexidade do código, eu trocaria também as aspas suplas por aspas simples sempre que possível e, claro, se for mais fácil (exceto para escape). O PHP demora (pouco) mais para avaliar as aspas duplas.

***[Dá uma olhada na resposta do @utluiz♦.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php)***

Comment: Poxa então, cara, como eu disse.. Eu coloque o seu código, e a ideia é que apareça a mensagem "Nenhum resultado no banco de dados para o argumento de pesquisa" certo? E quando eu fui testar deu o mesmo problema do meu: eu coloquei umas letras nada a ver pra testar e a mensagem não apareceu , como se estivesse no banco. O server está funcionando bem, o POST também. Eu usei a conexão com o bd de um código que já estava funcionando. Está realmente estranho, mas simplesmente não utiliza a informação. Acredito eu que nem mesmo esteja fazendo a consulta...

Comment: Então eu vou fazer uma recomendação: use PDO. Foi a melhor coisa que eu fiz até hoje. Vou postar um exemplo.

Comment: A tabela se chama login mesmo?

Comment: Concordo com o Not The Real HemingWay, PDO é o mais recomendado para trabalho com o banco de dados, pois além de ter um padrão de comportamento ele faz diversas validações de segurança (Sem falar que já está em OO).

Comment: sim, se chama login . Bom eu nunca trabalhei com PDO, eu aceito a sugestão, mas eu gostaria de resolver esse problema com esse método mesmo, afinal não é pra apresentar esse tipo de erro sem sentido. Gostaria de saber como resolver afinal

Comment: Beleza então. Pega o código que eu postei. Vai imprimir a query. Pegue a query e execute no MySQL. Veja a resposta do banco de dados se dá algum erro.

Comment: Eu peço desculpas. O acento grave é somente para marcar as colunas/campos. Strings são envoltas em aspas simples ou duplas no MySQL.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway eu fiz o que você pediu, mas como todas as outras coisas que eu testei não deu nem sinal de vida. Esse método parece interessante, mas infelizmente também não funcionou xP

Answer (score 0):

Gente fiz umas pesquisas baseadas nas coisas que vocês disseram pra mim e eu encontrei esse link aqui: http://respostas.guj.com.br/20509-fazer-consulta-no-banco-de-dados-e-retornar-valores (me perdoem se não puder colocar links de outros lugares)
Enfim acabou ficando assim:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","authenticationteste") or die(mysql_error());

$email = $_POST["email"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT senha from login where email = '$email'")or die(mysql_error());
$numrow = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrow > 0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            if($row['senha'] == $senha){ 
                echo"<script>alert('Login valido');</script>";
            }else{
                echo "<script>alert('Login e inválidos');</script>";
            }
        }// fim do while         
    }
```

?>

Se eu encontrar como funciona o código em PDO eu coloco também. Obrigada por tudo gente!

Comment: Isso só funciona se você usar um esquema muito inseguro de senha. O password_hash do PHP funciona diferente, por exemplo. Seu problema na pergunta é testar a validade do $res, pois o fato dele não achar usuário não o invalida. Tem uma resposta minha recente que dá um bom exemplo de como usar o password_verify para checar uma senha gravada com password_hash, e uma leitura sobre segurança que pode ajudar. Passarei os 2 links logo em seguida.

Comment: Exemplo de uso de password_verify: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/175001/70 | Leitura sobre Hashes seguros para senhas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70

Comment: Opa, eu dei uma olhada lá e usei o comando que você passou $seg_senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); deu certinho, porém agora preciso saber na parte de login, como fazer funcionar com a senha que a pessoa digitar lá, se puder me ajudar agradeço